# Apache RewriteRule redirection with url encoded

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-encoding

I have this URL (urlencoded twice):

```
http%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.cl%252F%2523test (translated: http://www.google.cl/#test)
```

And this Rewrite Rule:

```
RewriteRule /linkto/(.*?)/ ${unesc:$1} [R,L]
```

If i put this url in the browser:

```
http://localhost/linkto/http%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.cl%252F%2523test/data/
```

Apache redirects to http://www.google.cl/%23test instead of http://www.google.cl/#test

The problem ocurrs only with # (number sign).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try `NE` flag:

```
RewriteRule ^/?linkto/(.*?)/ ${unesc:$1} [R,L,NE,NC]
```

Comment: That work better... but redirect to: http://localhost/http://www.google.cl/#test instead of http://www.google.cl/#test

Comment: Solved using rewrite like this: RewriteRule ^/linkto/(.*?)/ ${unesc:$1} [R,L,NE,NC] Thanks !

Comment: ok perfect, glad that it worked. Please consider marking the answer as accepted to help out future visitors.

Comment: What is "${unesc:" function? is it documented?