# url encoded redirect in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I want to do a simple htaccess redirect. Hoping to avoid PHP if I can.

I want to redirect the user to the URL that will be trailing the request, like so:

`http://myexample.com/redirect/http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2Fask`

My htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule redirect/(.*) $1 [L,QSA]
```

However, I'm not getting the results I want. Is there a way to decode the value of `$1` and redirect to it? (It should be able to handle potentially long URLs with query strings) Any help would be awesome!

Comment: The answer was given here, but I do not think that it works with modern version of Apache - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18990593/apache-rewriterule-redirection-with-url-encoded `${unesc:$1}` is a RewriteMap enabled in server's config.

Comment: Are you *sure* apache isn't trapping the request (mod_security or something?) because it's got an encoded URL in it? If that's the case, the request will never even reach mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm this is tricky as it requires a change in Apache config also to let you use encoded slash e.g. `%2F` in URLs.

First add this line in Apache config:

```
AllowEncodedSlashes On
```

And restart Apache.

Then have this rule in your root .htaccess to let Apache decode and redirect:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/redirect/(http.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R,NE]
```

Comment: Tested with basic URIs and this works! Thanks! Will be testing more complex URIs soon.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using HTTP redirects? In HTTP response status code 301 Moved Permanently is used for permanent URL redirection. You may do something like `Redirect 301 / http://stackoverflow.com` instead.

Comment: He wants to use redirect URL from the requested uri, not hardcoded.